# Making parts of page not scrollable and making scroll-then-fixed to work on body larger then 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm a complete noob in javascript so i'm just copying things from internet for my portfolio project i have this semester and now i'm stuck with this thing not working

```
var elementPosition = $('#header_nav').offset();

$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top) {
        $('#header_nav').css('position', 'fixed').css('top', '0');
    } else {
        $('#header_nav').css('position', 'static');
    }    
});
```

When my page 100% wide this piece of code worked like a charm but as I have different ideas for my webpage now, I decided to stretch it so it's now 300% width of a browser window. And then i centered my header and sections in the middle of those 300% so it basically looks like this:

http://postimg.org/image/g7m9hj425/full/

I've managed to disable middle mouse button scroll with this piece of code:

```
$('body').mousedown(function(e){if(e.button==1)return false});
```

But, i still can't make scroll-then-fixed thing to work.

Thanks in advance, i hope i have been clear enough :)

Comment: Can i make the page so that top-left first pixel the first one in body but for example is the 1921. pixel, cause i think that causes my problems because when i reload my page it's blank and i need to scroll to the part with sections and navigation just like in the jsfiddle i provided

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried box sizing? 
here is a link of other people helping you with the question. 
http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=35015\
Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think it helps in this situation because when i go to the position of #left i get to scroll up and down because of my #Home, #About, #Gallery, #Literature and #Contact height and each one of them is 100% in height